# Read only new mail from nested mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, mime-message

I am trying to read nested email using java mail api. I mean if we have any email which contains old email as well in the body. How can i read only new mail from them?
I have written few lines of code because I think this is kind of message comes under MimeMultipart/alternative but didn't work.

Comment: Messages that are replied to?  There is no perfect way to separate new text from old text, especially in HTML messages.  If it's an *attached* message, it's type should be message/rfc822.

Comment: yes reply to message

Comment: Yes, every mail client does this differently.  It just inserts some text before the original text.  There is no standard for how this is done.